# full text justification

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I don't know why my text isn't fully justified left and right.

I have a screenshot of the text..and my preamble is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fullpage]{report}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{lettrine}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document}

\section{Ιστορικά στοιχεία}
\subsection{Τεχνολογία ψηφιοποιημένης σχεδίασης  και μηχανοποιημένης κοπής.}

\par{\lettrine[lines=2]{Ο}{όρος} της τεχνολογίας ψηφιοποιημένης σχεδίασης και μηχανοποιημένης κοπής ή αλλιώς \selectlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM} \selectlanguage{greek}προσδιορίζει τη συνεργασία ανάμεσα σε ένα σύστημα \selectlanguage{english}{CAD}\selectlanguage{greek} και ένα σύστημα \selectlanguage{english}{CAM} \selectlanguage{greek}προκειμένου να καθοδηγηθεί μια \- εργαλειομηχανή ηλεκτρονικά να κατασκευάσει το ψηφιοποιημένο σχέδιο.}

{Στην οδοντιατρική και για πάνω από $300$ χρόνια, ο μόνος τρόπος αναπαραγωγής δοντιών, προσθετικών αποκαταστάσεων ή γνάθων με ακρίβεια ($200$-$500$μ\selectlanguage{english}{m}) \selectlanguage{greek}ήταν με τη χρήση ελαστομερών υλικών και την αποτύπωση των δοντιών ή των γνάθων με αυτά τα υλικά. Ειδικότερα, στη μέθοδο με το αποτύπωμα, το θετικό τμήμα είναι τα δόντια ή η γνάθος και το αρνητικό τμήμα της μεθόδου το αποτυπωτικό υλικό. Αυτή η μέθοδος, που χρησιμοποιείται περισσότερα από $300$ χρόνια, δεν έχει αλλάξει δραστικά εκτός από τη βελτίωση των υλικών με την πάροδο των χρόνων. Η διαδικασία της αποτύπωσης, από θερμοδυναμικής άποψης, προκαλεί μια ανταλλαγή θερμότητας από το θετικό και το αρνητικό τμήμα καθώς και μείωση της εσωτερικής ενέργειας του αρνητικού τμήματος. Βάση των παραπάνω, προκαλείται μια μεγάλη μεταβολή της ενθαλπίας (ΔΗ) του συστήματος  γιατί απαιτεί μεγάλη κατανάλωση ενέργειας.}

{Η βασική λογική πίσω από το \selectlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM} \selectlanguage{greek} είναι η χρήση ενός συστήματος που δεν έχει πολλές ανταλλαγές ενέργειας με το περιβάλλον. Ακόμα, αυτό το σύστημα θα πρέπει να είναι θερμοδυναμικά ουδέτερο, δηλαδή να μην υπάρχουν μετατροπές σε άλλες μορφές ενέργειας κατά την λήψη του αποτυπώματος. Γι'αυτό το λόγο, η κβαντική ενέργεια με τη μορφή της ενίσχυσης του φωτός με εξαναγκασμένη εκπομπή ακτινοβολίας \selectlanguage{english}{LASER}\selectlanguage{greek} αποτελεί την κατάλληλη λύση \parencite{Duret1}.}

\par{Με αυτή τη λογική οι \selectlanguage{english}{Duret}\selectlanguage{greek}και συνεργάτες το $1974$ ξεκίνησαν να πειραματίζονται με σκοπό να αντικαταστήσουν το αρνητικό τμήμα στη περίπτωση του αποτυπώματος με μια ακτίνα \selectlanguage{english}{LASER}\selectlanguage{greek}. } 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This code compiles fine as soon as I have added  `\yusepackage{biblatex}`, and yields the expected reult (i.e. not ragged right). You must have something else in your code which inhibits hyphenation. B.t.w.  you forgot a blank space in `\selectlanguage{english}{Duret} \selectlanguage{greek}και` in the last paragraph.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the typesetting issue you're encountering using  just the code you've provided. Does your "real" document maybe contain a stray `\raggedright` directive? Off-topic: `\par` does *not* take an argument.

Comment: No, the document doesn't contain the \raggedright. However, I have tried it, didn't like it and erased it..But now I think I am stuck with it.

Comment: @PetrosMourouzis copy the code from your question to a new document and run it, and you will see that it does not make the image that you show.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I can't understand why the raggedright remains in the first document, maybe if I erase the .pdf or the .aux file it will be corrected.

Comment: I believe something in the title page: I think that a \centering is making all this:

Comment: @PetrosMourouzis - Aah, so now there's a title page as well, along with a `\centering` instruction. Given that the screenshot you posted shows ragged-right alignment rather than centered alignment, there must also be an instruction that somehow terminates centered alignment and initiates ragged-right (aka `flushleft`) alignment. Please check your document for just such an instruction.

Comment: Yes, there was a flush left in the title page...so problem solved

Comment: Next time please post the image of the code you are posting not from the original document otherwise it is very confusing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that you have a `\raggedright` instruction *somewhere* before the `\subsection` directive in the document that gave rise to the screenshot you posted. (Well, either `\raggedright` or `\begin{flushleft}` and, later on, `\end{flushleft}`.) The `\raggedright` instruction was likely inserted in order to avoid (a) hyphenation and (b) an overfull line in the two-line subsection header. At least, *without* the `\raggedright` directive, the code you posted creates just these two problems; *with* `\raggedright`, one gets the subsection header that's shown in your screenshot.

A safe way to constrain the scope of `\raggedright` to sectioning headers is to load the `sectsty` package and to run the instruction `\allsectionsfont{\raggedright}`.

Some additional comments: (A) Your code contains eight [8!] instances of

```
\selectlanguage{english}{...} \selectlanguage{greek}
```

It would be much more efficient to run `\foreignlanguage{english}{...}`.

(B) To typeset scientific units, such as "micro-meter", it's better to load the `siunitx` package and to input

```
(200--500\,\si{\micro\meter})
```

than to write

```
($200$-$500$μ\selectlanguage{english}{m})\selectlanguage{greek}
```

(C) `\par` does *not* take an argument. To create a paragraph break, simply insert an all-blank line.

---

The modified MWE (minimum working example) would look like this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,fullpage]{report}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage{sectsty} % <-- new
\allsectionsfont{\raggedright} % ragged-right mode, no hyph.
\usepackage{siunitx} % <-- new

\providecommand\parencite[1]{} % or: load the 'biblatex' package...

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example

\section{Ιστορικά στοιχεία}
\subsection{Τεχνολογία ψηφιοποιημένης σχεδίασης  και 
μηχανοποιημένης κοπής.}

\lettrine[lines=2]{Ο}{όρος} της τεχνολογίας ψηφιοποιημένης 
σχεδίασης και μηχανοποιημένης κοπής ή αλλιώς 
\foreignlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM} προσδιορίζει τη 
συνεργασία ανάμεσα σε ένα σύστημα \foreignlanguage{english}{CAD} 
και ένα σύστημα \foreignlanguage{english}{CAM} προκειμένου 
να καθοδηγηθεί μιαεργαλειομηχανή ηλεκτρονικά να κατασκευάσει 
το ψηφιοποιημένο σχέδιο.

Στην οδοντιατρική και για πάνω από 300 χρόνια, ο μόνος 
τρόπος αναπαραγωγής δοντιών, προσθετικών αποκαταστάσεων 
ή γνάθων με ακρίβεια (200--500\,\si{\micro\meter}) ήταν 
με τη χρήση ελαστομερών υλικών και την αποτύπωση των 
δοντιών ή των γνάθων με αυτά τα υλικά. Ειδικότερα, 
στη μέθοδο με το αποτύπωμα, το θετικό τμήμα είναι τα 
δόντια ή η γνάθος και το αρνητικό τμήμα της μεθόδου 
το αποτυπωτικό υλικό. Αυτή η μέθοδος, που 
χρησιμοποιείται περισσότερα από 300 χρόνια, δεν έχει 
αλλάξει δραστικά εκτός από τη βελτίωση των υλικών με 
την πάροδο των χρόνων. Η διαδικασία της αποτύπωσης, 
από θερμοδυναμικής άποψης, προκαλεί μια ανταλλαγή 
θερμότητας από το θετικό και το αρνητικό τμήμα 
καθώς και μείωση της εσωτερικής ενέργειας του 
αρνητικού τμήματος. Βάση των παραπάνω, προκαλείται 
μια μεγάλη μεταβολή της ενθαλπίας (ΔΗ) του συστήματος 
γιατί απαιτεί μεγάλη κατανάλωση ενέργειας.

Η βασική λογική πίσω από το \foreignlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM}  
είναι η χρήση ενός συστήματος που δεν έχει πολλές 
ανταλλαγές ενέργειας με το περιβάλλον. Ακόμα, αυτό 
το σύστημα θα πρέπει να είναι θερμοδυναμικά ουδέτερο, 
δηλαδή να μην υπάρχουν μετατροπές σε άλλες μορφές 
ενέργειας κατά την λήψη του αποτυπώματος. Γι'αυτό 
το λόγο, η κβαντική ενέργεια με τη μορφή της ενίσχυσης 
του φωτός με εξαναγκασμένη εκπομπή ακτινοβολίας 
\foreignlanguage{english}{LASER} αποτελεί την κατάλληλη 
λύση \parencite{Duret1}.

Με αυτή τη λογική οι \foreignlanguage{english}{Duret} και 
συνεργάτες το 1974 ξεκίνησαν να πειραματίζονται με σκοπό 
να αντικαταστήσουν το αρνητικό τμήμα στη περίπτωση του 
αποτυπώματος με μια ακτίνα \foreignlanguage{english}{LASER}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for the comments, I follow your instructions, everything was ok except for the alignment which remained the same, I look for a \raggedright but it doesn't exist in the document. There are only 260 lines so it will be easy to spot it..

Comment: Maybe some package or package option, which is not in your post, adds `\raggedright` internally.

Comment: Final comment: The OP eventually reported that the document part in question was typeset in a `flushleft` environment -- which is equivalent to having run `\raggedright`.